# Access Database TransferText Performance Improvement

Tags: vb.net, performance, ms-access, vba

Looking into increasing the performance of our .net tool that imports data into an access db. Inserting line by line in a loop should be slower than the .TransferText method so I'm looking at some other ways to perform the same import but with better performance.

Currently we do the following:

1. The .NET app detects the new text file arrival
2. Places it into a datatable
3. Verifies the data
4. Creates the Access db
5. Creates a vba module and inserts vba code
6. Invokes the DoCmd.TransferText method inside access
7. Misc other processes etc

Is there any better performing techniques I should look into?

Thanks

Comment: your ".net tool" sounds like it is some vba code and not really .NET at all (no such method as `TransferText` in of NET4.0).  So, it very likely could be faster writing some code optimized for performance.

Comment: As outlined, in #6 it invokes the transfertext method. Since it creates a new clean db each time it has to inject the vba code into it as its believed to be faster to run it from within access. 

Im looking to replace the transfertext method with something else and/or different design but it needs to be faster bottom line and not as concerned about how we get there.

Comment: Have you looked at using ADODB recordsets to directly import the data and bypass transfertext (which is slow) and inserting a vba module (which shouldn't take long, but is unnecessary)?

Comment: It's also hard to spot the issue without seeing any code at all.

Comment: This is what concerns me as a possible performance increase if there is something faster than the .TransferText method. If there is I would like to know as I can remove the method call and add whatever code is better and faster.

DoCmd.TransferText is the code as its a method in VBA we are invoking from VB.NET

Comment: Leave vba out of it entirely. Research how use adodb recordsets. You can connect to the text file and pull it into a recordset and then output it to the access database.

Comment: Yes I know how to use ado.net but I want to know which technique has a performance gain over .TransferText is my original question and current issue.

Comment: We are running the TransferText method via Access Object Model in VB.NET. Not sure how much COM overhead can be eliminated by going with ADO.NET but Im finding really hard to locate some performance data on TransferText vs ADO.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The .TransferText method was indeed slower but there was some code optimizations that I also was able to do like keeping the database open while it was being used and not opening and closing it each iteration. Also, I used DAO to connect to the db and execute some sql statements bulk inserting the textfile records which I directly connected to instead.

```
db.Execute("INSERT INTO " & sMdbTableName & " SELECT * FROM [Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;Database=" & localPath & "]." & sTextFile & ";")
```

This was a heck of allot faster when I put each of the improvements all together. 
I added timer code and tested each technique separately. The results were that using DAO with bult insert statement directly connected to the text files were about 5 times faster.

Thanks for the replies and help